# I wouId like to attach the wsl sagemath kernel to spyder in windowsw-10; i.e., spyder installed in windows-10, not in wsl. Get connecting... forever

Tags: kernel, spyder, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sage

In spyder: Consoles -> connect to existing ->
\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\USER.venvs\39env\sage\local\var\lib\sage\venv-python3.9\share\jupyter\kernels\sagemath\kernel.json -> leads to a Connecting to kernel... forever.

Cat the kernel file  kernel.json ->
{"argv": ["/home/USER/.venvs/39env/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.9/bin/sage", "--python", "-m", "sage.repl.ipython_kernel", "-f", "{connection_file}"], "display_name": "SageMath 10.2", "language": "sage"}

Any help on what to try next will be most appreciated. spyder, spyder-kernel, spyder-notebook are all installed with conda. About -> * Spyder version: 5.5.1  (conda)

- Python version: 3.10.13 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.15.2
- PyQt5 version: 5.15.10
- Operating System: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0

I hoped to use the sagemath kernel inside spyder-notebook for ipynb files